How do I find the hostname of my Azure App (.azurewebsites.net)?
I created an Azure Bot Resource and navigated to its linked Azure App. However I need to know what the hostname of this application is because I am importing this application to use for my Bot Framework Composer during publishing of the bot. Every online resource I am looking at says that my hostname is from the application service url with '.azurewebsites.net' but I do not know where to find it on my Azure Bot or Azure Application's profile. Where do I find this? I am the owner of this bot on Azure Portal so I should have access to view it if it is there.
I wonder if it is because I have not created a web app. However, I don't know if I need it. I created my bot on Bot Framework Composer linked to the API of my own external software so it works fine on the Emulator. I just need to publish it.
Option to create a webapp with sample for authentication flow - I do not need authentication for my bot though do I?
This is what my Azure Bot Overview looks like on the portal.
Azure Portal - Overview
Azure Bot > Configuration
Configuration
App ID, into Manage Password from previous image gives the Microsoft App
Microsoft Linked App
For context, my bot is essentially a chatbot linked to my own chatbot service like chatgpt on microsoft teams
I have tried using just the display name of the application but there is an error so I am trying to find the azurewebsites.net link.

How did you create the Azure Bot? Which programming language is your Bot using?

You can see the Azure web app's hostname in the Azure Bot=>Overview=>Messaging Endpoint (or) Tags, refer Image.

Thank you for your response! I have updated my original post to show what I see in my Azure Bot, Overview.
My Messaging Endpoint and Tags are both empty and I am not sure why. I just created a bot using the Azure Portal. I also made the logic for the bot on Bot Framework Composer (there are two options when creating a bot, .NET or Node, and I chose Node). Now I want to publish my logic for the bot from Bot Framework Composer onto the existing resource of the Azure Bot on my portal but it asks for hostname and I am not sure where to retrieve it.

If you have created Azure Bot using Portal, you have to create an App Service as well and link it to the Azure Bot. Instead, you can directly configure the deployment from Bot framework composer by creating new resources.

When I created the bot on the portal, it was already connected to a Microsoft App Id under Configuration. When I clicked into Manage Password, I get to the Microsoft App Service.

When you create an Azure bot, it creates the App registration(the page you are referring to) to register the application. But you have to create the App Service manually.

Is the first image in my post what you are referring to by 'creating the App Service manually'?

Check if you can see the App Service with the same name as Azure Bot under the same resource group.

If you can see the Image of your Azure Bot, Messaging Endpoint is empty. So, the App Service is not linked to your Azure Bot.

I see! then to link the app service to my azure bot, what should I do? Is it the first image in my original post?

You have to create a new web app and add the hostname in the Azure Bot's Messaging endpoint under configuration. Eg: https://appname.azurewebsites.net/api/messages

Sorry for the late reply! If i follow the path in my first image to create a web application under quickstart, it leads me to create an app, a tutorial to:
'Quickstart: Sign in users and get an access token in a Node.js web app using the authorization code flow
In this quickstart, you download and run a code sample that demonstrates how a Node.js web app can sign in users by using the authorization code flow. The code sample also demonstrates how to get an access token to call Microsoft...'
I think this is creating another app, instead of integrating my bot into this empty app service?

Search for Azure App Service and Create new. Refer Image

Or should i instead create a new Web App (directly from my Microsoft Azure Portal) and then I connect it to my Azure Bot using the Messaging endpoint? and then take the hostname from here?
Then how about my app registration that was made previously and was directly connected to my Azure Bot? Do I just leave it as is? I do not need to connect it to the web app?

Create web app and you can use it as hostname in the deployment template in Bot framework Composer. This will configure the connection between the web app and Bot. How do you want to deploy the bot? using bot composer or visual studio code or cli?

Check the below answer for clear explanation to deploy the bot to Azure.

I see! I do not have much experience with Azure. Considering that my Bot Framework Composer is being deployed on the Azure Bot and accesses an external api, should I select code, container or static web app when creating my web app

You have to select code and Node as runtime stack.

Host name refers to the name of the Azure App Service.
To deploy a Bot, you have to create a new Azure Bot and Azure App Service in Portal.

Search for Azure App Service and create new.

I have created a Node(Preview) Azure Bot using Bot framework composer.

Navigate to Azure Bot=>Configuration=>Manage Password=>Certificates & Secrets=>Client Secrets, create a secret. Note the Secret value to use it as Microsoft App Password.
Create a new publishing profile in Bot framework composer to deploy the Bot to Azure.

Publish=>Publishing Profile=>Add New:


Select Import Existing resources to deploy the Bot to existing resource.


Update below mentioned details in the displayed template:
{
  "name": "<subscription_name>",
  "environment": "dev",
  "tenantId": "<Azure_tenant_ID>",
  "hostname": "<Your_App_service_name>",  //newly created app service name
  "runtimeIdentifier": "win-x64",
  "resourceGroup": "<resourcegroup_name>",
  "botName": "<Your_Azure_Bot_name>",
  "subscriptionId": "<subscription_ID>",
  "region": "<resourcegroup_region>",
  "appServiceOperatingSystem": "windows",
  "scmHostDomain": "scm.azurewebsites.net",
  "luisResource": "",
  "settings": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "InstrumentationKey": "",
      "connectionString": ""
    },
    "cosmosDb": {
      "cosmosDBEndpoint": "",
      "authKey": "",
      "databaseId": "",
      "containerId": ""
    },
    "blobStorage": {
      "connectionString": "",
      "container": ""
    },
    "luis": {
      "authoringKey": "",
      "authoringEndpoint": "",
      "endpointKey": "",
      "endpoint": "",
      "region": ""
    },
    "qna": {
      "subscriptionKey": "",
      "endpoint": ""
    },
    "MicrosoftAppId": "<Microsoft_APP_ID_available_in_Azurebot_configuration>",
    "MicrosoftAppPassword": "<Microsoft_APP_password_created_via_Azurebot_configuration>"
  }
}


This process creates the publish profile to deploy the Bot to Azure:


Select the Bot => choose the publish profile as target and click on Publish Selected bots to deploy the bot.





Deployed the Bot to Azure:



Thank you so much! Can I ask why you have subscription name inside 'name' for the imported resources JSON?
Additionally, just to clarify are all these names to be in lower caps or are they case sensitive? So if my bot name in azure bot is 'Test' then will the name be 'test' or 'Test' in the imported resources JSON?

It is the default template which generates automatically when you select important existing resources.

Can I ask how you got your App Password under configuration? Is it Manage Password to open up the app registration and then clients and secrets?

If so, my only difference from yours is that I am using linux instead of windows. And yet, I am getting an error when I attempt to publish my bot (the last step of your answer):
DEPLOY ZIP ERROR There was a problem publishing bot assets (zip deploy).
{"stack":"Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .scm.azurewebsites.net\n at
GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)","message":"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .scm.azurewebsites.net", "code":"ENOTFOUND","config":())

Can you try selecting Create new resources instead of Importing existing resources.

I am unable to create resource group under create new resources due to access rights issues. I need my boss to do this. The problem with 'Hand off to admin' is that it will send this to my admin who will send me back the json that i will need to add again through import existing resources right?

If you create new resources, you won't get this issue. I will check if I can find workaround for your issue.

After playing around, I found that if i change the 'scmHostDomain' to 'azurewebsites.net' the error now changes to

DEPLOY ZIP ERROR -
There was a problem publishing bot assets (zip deploy).
("stack":"Error: Request failed with status code 404\n at createError (C:\...Bot Framework Composer\resources\ app.asar.unpacked\extensions\azurePublish\da ist\extension.js:105969:17)
...
at settle at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
at endReadableNT (stream_readable.js:118 3:12)
at processTicksAndRejections internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)","message":"Request failed with status code 404","config":{}}

Looks like the issue is with Linux environment, try using windows.

Could I ask why you would say it is a linux error?

I have gone through few GitHub issues regarding the same error, I could see many are getting this error in Linux.

I am getting the same error message when i change to windows,
when 'scmHostDomain': 'scm.azurewebsites.net', it is saying that addr not found
and 'azurewebsites.net', it is saying that 404 error

Can you deploy using VS code or cli?

What should the subscription name under 'name' in the Imported Resources of the Bot Framework Composer be?

It should be name of your Azure subscription, you can find it under subscriptions in portal.

i changed my subscription name and it still does not work, to deploy it through vs code is there a documentation on how to do so?

You can also deploy the bot using GitHub actions(if you can push your code to GitHub), refer to my answer. you can follow from Pushed the whole project code to GitHub step.

For the cli command of node, do the names, appPassword and id have to be in "" or '' or neither

should be enclosed with "".

wait im confused, i dont have to the node command at the start because i already provisioned resources right

so i should export my bot framework composer project as a zip and then push it onto github then on my azure web app i link it to that github repo is it?

You don't have to compress as zip, can directly push the project to your repository.

so i dont need to do the node command? also i am not sure how to directly push the project to repository since the project only exists on the Framework Composer and can only be exported as a zip

i am so sorry but is it possible to schedule a call, it is completely fine if not

you can find the project folder path available in bot composer. Image

You do not have sufficient permissions to assign role-based access to a managed identity within this resource group and configure federated credentials. If you wish to continue, please select an existing identity below. The identity must have a Website Contributor or higher role on the app.
when choosing authentication after selecting the github repo that i want

but if i choose basic authentication:
SCM basic authentication is disabled for your app. Click here to go to your configuration settings to enable, or choose the "User-assigned identity" option below.

Enable Scm basic auth setting in web app=>configuration

I am getting the following build error:
...node:events:497
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'D:\a...\node_modules\adaptive expressions\src\triggerTrees\index.ts'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {errno: -4066, code: 'EMFILE', syscall: 'open', path: 'D:...\node_modules\adaptive-expressions\src\triggerTrees\index.ts'}

this error exists both when i use node_modules and when i remove it from the github repository

Did you configure deployment settings in your project?

i think it is because even though on my git repository i specified to use node version 16, on the github actions on azure portal when it builds my repository and the packages it is set to use version 20, is there any way I can overwrite that or edit it to use version 16?
"Node.js v20.13.1"

in my environment variable in azure portal i specify version 16, so in deployment center settings it is also showing version 16 but when it builds on github actions it is building with version 20

This is my yml file that i cant edit and push to repo-
jobs:
build:
runs-on: windows-latest
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v4

  - name: Set up Node.js version
    uses: actions/setup-node@v3
    with:
      node-version: '16.x'

  - name: npm install, build, and test
    run: |
      npm install
      npm run build --if-present
      npm run test --if-present
  
  - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
    with:
      name: node-app
      path: .


i think it needs to be checkout@v3 but i can't commit and push the yml file, so i need to change it somewhere in the azure portal

ok i used the linux web app and i removed the yml file and ran the github in the deployment server and it worked, but how am i able to use this web app now?

Add the web app's browser url by adding /api/messages to it in the Bot=>configuration=>messaging endpoint. Ex:https://appname.azurewebsites.net/api/messages

I already did do that yay.. but now that the web app has been deployed how do i run it, currently the bot is a teams bot so how do i open it up on my teams?

it says that it is deployed at appname.azurewebsites.net but when i open it- it simply gives the message 'Cannot GET /'

You just have to Test in web chat of Azure Bot as mentioned in answer.

ah but when i test in web chat, it is not connecting to my bot service, the logic that i coded out which works in the emulator cannot be seen in the current web chat

Did you add Microsoft App ID in your project?

to my microsoft web app? where do i add in my app id from azure bot to my microsoft web app?

In settings=>appsettings.json

under my Web App portal > Settings, there is no appsetting.json
to clarify: you are referring to add my app id from Azure Bot to Web App right

yes, you can see settings folder in your project. and you are right about appid.

i added it in and deployed it again and then checked the test in web chat but it still does not work as expected, there is no response from the bot

after deploying there is a link right below appname.azurewebsites.net but when i open it it simply says 'Cannot GET ' i think this is why the messaging endpoints is not working as well, there is something wrong with the microsoft web app

is there something that i need to do in the app service in microsoft web app?

You don't have to run the web app. you just have to link the web app with bot and test the bot in Test in web chat.

If you go through the other so answer I have shared above, you can see the "PublishTargets" configuration. You have to set the the Appid and app password and the other values as mentioned in the so answer

Yup my publishtargets configuration is all set under settings > appsettings.json
and i have linked the web app with the bot using the app id but when i test the bot on Test in web chat, is there any way to check how the app is processing the messages received? or if it is even receiving these messages?

Did you also add the app password?

yes, same place as what was mentioned in your appsettings.json

[onTurnError] unhandled error DialogContextError: user.data is not a list or array.
at /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/dialogContext.js:40:19
at Generator.throw ()
at rejected (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/dialogContext.js:6:65)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
error: 'user.data is not a list or array.',
dialogContext: {
activeDialog: 'SetProperty[=user.data]2',
parent: 'BotName',
stack: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
}

when i check the logs on my Web App portal > Log Stream, i get the error above when i send a message. Not sure what is causing the error considering I am using the same files that work within the Bot Framework Composer.

When I restart the chat, it is supposed to send an Activity Greeting but I get thrown an error instead:
server listening on port 8080
2024-08-02T07:28:03.2280750Z Terminated
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6482331Z [onTurnError] unhandled error DialogContextError: The clientSecret parameter is required.
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483143Z at /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/dialogContext.js:40:19
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483273Z at Generator.throw ()
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483321Z at rejected (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/dialogContext.js:6:65)

2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483363Z at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483401Z error: Error: The clientSecret parameter is required.
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483438Z at Object.validateStringParameter (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/adal-node/lib/argument.js:37:13)
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483477Z at AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/adal-node/lib/authentication-context.js:282:14)

2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483511Z at /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/microsoftAppCredentials.js:49:48
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483566Z at new Promise ()
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483600Z at MicrosoftAppCredentials. (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/microsoftAppCredentials.js:48:40)
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483628Z at Generator.next ()
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483659Z at /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/microsoftAppCredentials.js:15:71

2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483687Z at new Promise ()
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483719Z at __awaiter (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/microsoftAppCredentials.js:11:12)
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483752Z at MicrosoftAppCredentials.refreshToken (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/botframework-connector/lib/auth/microsoftAppCredentials.js:46:16),
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483785Z dialogContext: {
2024-08-02T07:28:08.6483831Z activeDialog: 'SendActivity[${SendActivity_Greeting()}]',
parent: 'TestHaleriumBot',
stack: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]

what is the expected output that i should see on Log Stream (on verbose mode on Azure Web App portal) after 1) starting the web chat, 2) sending my first message

Did you create the basic Bot by following the MSDOC or is it your own code?

I did not use my own code but i used the frontend of the framework composer to create 'if/else conditions' and 'send a response' boxes within the bot framework composer [under the flowchat view]

Can you try adding npm install as startup command and check.

like just npm install under the web app>settings>configuration>startup commands

yes, thats correct.

the bot still does not respond to my messages, for each message i send it just keeps creating and closing containers

Raise a new question and provide your code, error details and steps followed as the issue could be related to the code, will try from my end and check.

whether or not i have npm install in the configs, it keeps creating, starting and stopping containers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78825670/bot-from-bot-framework-composer-deployed-on-azure-web-app-through-azure-bot-but
here is the new question, thanks!
