Bot from Bot Framework Composer deployed on Azure Web App through Azure Bot but when testing web chat on Bot, why is there no response from the bot?
I have created a bot on Bot Framework composer but I had a lot of issues with deployment through 'Create resources' and 'Import resources'. Finally I used github to deploy it on Azure Web App. But now when I test in the 'Test Web Chat' in the associated Azure Bot portal, there is none of the responses from the bot (which previously worked within the bot framework composer). For context, I am creating a bot which takes in the user's response and send it to an external api of mine and returns a reply to the user. However it is not working. When I go to the Web App's Log Stream right now I am getting the following error:
for every restart it creates, starts and stops a container then it just records no trace no matter what message i send (still no response from bot and not sure how to debug to find out what the bot is reading and if it is even calling the api that i have connected to it in the bot framework composer):
This is the first page of my error: Page1OfError
This is the second page of my error: Page2OfError
This is the third page of my error: Page3OfError
This is my previous stackoverflow chat from which I received help to successfully deploy my bot on Azure Web App: here
This is my AppName.dialog file:
{
  "$kind": "Microsoft.AdaptiveDialog",
  "$designer": {
    "name": "AppName",
    "description": "",
    "id": "xxx"
  },
  "autoEndDialog": true,
  "defaultResultProperty": "dialog.result",
  "triggers": [
    {
      "$kind": "Microsoft.OnConversationUpdateActivity",
      "$designer": {
        "id": "xxx",
        "comment": "This trigger runs when a conversation update activity is sent to the bot. This indicates a user or bot being added or removed from a conversation."
      },
      "actions": [
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.Foreach",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "xxx",
            "name": "Loop: for each item",
            "comment": "For each member added to the conversation."
          },
          "itemsProperty": "turn.Activity.membersAdded",
          "actions": [
            {
              "$kind": "Microsoft.IfCondition",
              "$designer": {
                "id": "xxx",
                "name": "Branch: if/else",
                "comment": "Checks that that member added ID does not match the bot ID. This prevents the greeting message from being sent when the bot is added to a conversation."
              },
              "condition": "=string(dialog.foreach.value.id) != string(turn.Activity.Recipient.id)",
              "actions": [
                {
                  "$kind": "Microsoft.SetProperty",
                  "$designer": {
                    "id": "xxx"
                  },
                  "property": "user.isNew",
                  "value": true
                },
                {
                  "$kind": "Microsoft.SendActivity",
                  "$designer": {
                    "id": "xxx",
                    "name": "Send a response"
                  },
                  "activity": "${SendActivity_Greeting()}"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "value": "dialog.foreach.value"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "$kind": "Microsoft.OnUnknownIntent",
      "$designer": {
        "id": "xxx",
        "comment": "This trigger fires when an incoming activity is not handled by any other trigger."
      },
      "actions": [
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.IfCondition",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "xxx",
            "comment": "whatever user has said"
          },
          "condition": "=turn.activity.text == \"refresh\" || user.isNew",
          "actions": [
            {
              "$kind": "Microsoft.SetProperty",
              "$designer": {
                "id": "xxx"
              },
              "property": "user.isNew",
              "value": false
            },
            {
              "$kind": "Microsoft.SetProperty",
              "$designer": {
                "id": "xxx"
              },
              "property": "user.data",
              "value": [
                {
                  "role": "user",
                  "message": "${turn.activity.text}"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$kind": "Microsoft.LogAction",
              "$designer": {
                "id": "logAction"
              },
              "text": "User Data: ${user.data}"
            }
          ],
          "elseActions": [
            {
              "$kind": "Microsoft.SetProperty",
              "$designer": {
                "id": "xxx"
              },
              "property": "turn.newInput",
              "value": [
                {
                  "role": "user",
                  "message": "${turn.activity.text}"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$kind": "Microsoft.SetProperty",
              "$designer": {
                "id": "xxx"
              },
              "property": "user.data",
              "value": "=union(user.data,turn.newInput)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.HttpRequest",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "xxx"
          },
          "method": "POST",
          "resultProperty": "turn.results",
          "contentType": "application/json",
          "body": {
            "data": "${user.data}"
          },
          "url": "https://my_api_service/user_prompt"
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SendActivity",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "xxx"
          },
          "activity": "${SendActivity_xxx()}"
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SetProperty",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "xxx"
          },
          "property": "turn.output",
          "value": [
            {
              "role": "assistant",
              "message": "${turn.results.content}"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SetProperty",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "xxx"
          },
          "property": "user.data",
          "value": "=union(user.data,turn.output)"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "generator": "AppName.lg",
  "id": "AppName",
  "recognizer": "AppName.lu.qna"
}


When I run the Availability & Performance on the Azure Bot:
Process Full List
This shows the list of all the processes running in your Linux instances.
No process data is found because your app has not spun up or has not been running during this time period.

I have provided the code after censoring private information in the code above. I am so sorry but I don't feel comfortable sharing the github repo link as it has private information (you can let me know exactly which part of the code and I can censor and send it back to you)

Provide frontend code which you have modified in the default application.

Could you provide an example of what you are looking for? Filename? Where to find this code? (On the original post is the code for the logic of the bot)

Hi, is there anything you need from me?

If you haven't resolved this already, I would suggest bypassing Composer and just re-publishing the bot from either Visual Studio (best to select the option to remove existing content) or the az cli.
